# Apache Tomcate not starting (http://localhost:8080/)

Tags: java, tomcat, environment-variables, localhost

I am trying to start my APACHE TOMCAT SERVER version apache-tomcat-8.5.73
when i click on startup one window will open and after some time get below message and screen get close every time.
i have checked environment variable it is defined correct, i am try to catch the issue but did not.

```
2021 12:53:01.819 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
29-Dec-2021 12:53:02.250 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
29-Dec-2021 12:53:02.388 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 1736 ms
29-Dec-2021 12:53:02.451 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
29-Dec-2021 12:53:02.452 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/8.5.73]
29-Dec-2021 12:53:02.493 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [C:\IIQ\apache-tomcat-8.5.73\apache-tomcat-8.5.73\webapps\identityiq.war]
2021-12-29 12:53:47,677  WARN localhost-startStop-1 sailpoint.server.JavaLoggingSuppressor:100 - The application detected that a custom logging file exists: C:\IIQ\apache-tomcat-8.5.73\apache-tomcat-8.5.73\conf\logging.properties.  The application was unable to suppress various debugging messages.
2021-12-29 12:53:47,689  WARN localhost-startStop-1 sailpoint.server.JavaLoggingSuppressor:101 - In order to manually suppress Jersey debugging messages, the following logger levels must be adjusted to ''WARNING'': com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig, com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.DeferredResourceConfig, and com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl
2021-12-29 12:53:47,691  WARN localhost-startStop-1 sailpoint.server.JavaLoggingSuppressor:102 - In order to manually suppress JSF debugging messages, the following logger level must be adjusted to ''SEVERE'': org.apache.myfaces.shared_tomahawk.renderkit.html.HtmlRendererUtils
```

Comment: Try to launch Tomcat from the command line, you may see additional messages.

Comment: if lauching from cmmand line i get below message and after sometime startup screen get close automatically'

Comment: Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\IIQ\apache-tomcat-8.5.73\apache-tomcat-8.5.73"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\IIQ\apache-tomcat-8.5.73\apache-tomcat-8.5.73"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\IIQ\apache-tomcat-8.5.73\apache-tomcat-8.5.73\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_251"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\IIQ\apache-tomcat-8.5.73\apache-tomcat-8.5.73\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\IIQ\apache-tomcat-8.5.73\apache-tomcat-8.5.73\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
Using CATALINA_OPTS:   ""

Comment: What do you see in error logs ?